# memory out of exception in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am using Lumia 640 for development.
I got an memory out of exception in windows phone 8.1 Silver Light Application. 
I have tried to dispose stream, remove bitmap from memory but still facing this issues.

When collecting More than 5 Images using `CameraCaptureTask` it will throws **"memory out of exception"**.

I am posing My Demo Code Here.

```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CameraCaptureTask cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
        cameraCaptureTask.Show();
        cameraCaptureTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(this.CameraCaptureTaskCompleted);
    }

    private async void CameraCaptureTaskCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("[ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage](MB) : \n" + (DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage / 1024 / 1024));

            Image attachedImage = new Image();

            Stream fileStream = e.ChosenPhoto;

            string strFolderName = "Capture";

            IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + ".JPG";
            if (!isf.DirectoryExists(strFolderName))
            {
                isf.CreateDirectory(strFolderName);
            }

            if (isf.FileExists(strFolderName + "\\" + fileName))
            {
                isf.DeleteFile(strFolderName + "\\" + fileName);
            }
            IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.CreateFile(strFolderName + "\\" + fileName);

            int bytesRead = 0;
            var bufferSize = Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length);
            var fileBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            while ((bytesRead = await fileStream.ReadAsync(fileBytes, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
            {
                isfs.Write(fileBytes, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            BitmapImage bitImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitImage.SetSource(fileStream);

            bitImage.DecodePixelType = DecodePixelType.Physical;
            bitImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation;
            bitImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation;


            double dblRation = (double)bitImage.PixelWidth / bitImage.PixelHeight;

            //if (bitImage.PixelWidth > bitImage.PixelHeight)
            //{
            //    bitImage.DecodePixelWidth = 200;

            //    bitImage.DecodePixelHeight = 200 / (int)dblRation;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    bitImage.DecodePixelHeight = 200;

            //    bitImage.DecodePixelWidth = (int)(200 * dblRation);
            //}


            attachedImage.Source = bitImage;

            GC.Collect();

            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            fileStream.Flush();
            fileStream.Dispose();
            fileStream.Close();
            bitImage = null;
            fileStream = null;
            fileBytes = null;


            sp.Children.Add(attachedImage);
            Debug.WriteLine("[ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage](MB) : \n" + (DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage / 1024 / 1024));
        }
    }
```

It is just demo code. When I pick first image it will rise from 8 MB to 37 MB usage.But in real application it will rise from 64 MB to 112 MB.

Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: You get this errors when the selected images displayed in screen?

Comment: No, It is a random error. Means when Memory is coming more than 300 MB. When I select Image from camera it added +30 MB more So when I have selected more than 5 Images the memory cross 300 and it's crashed.

Comment: I too got the same error in my app, while picking image. so displayed image by reducing its DecodePixelWidth.

Comment: Yes, I have tried same. Check I have commented same code in my post. It's not helpful